# trying to build complex nested join

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to figure out the best way to join these queries, and I'm stumped - I'd poay for help on this!

Query 1 gives me the rows I want perfectly - 
Query 2 gives me entries from another table where the data is relative to each row from query 1

I can't seem to build a proper statement to return rows that include results from Query 2 in each row from Query 1.  NOTE: "object_id AS id" in Query 1 = "post_id" in Query 2

Query 1:

```
SELECT LEFT(post_content, 40) AS excerpt, id, post_title, guid FROM wp_posts 
   WHERE id IN 
    (SELECT object_id AS id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 74)
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT post_id, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'allowed' THEN meta_value END) allowed,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'amenities' THEN meta_value END) amenities,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'trail-type' THEN meta_value END) trailtype,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'weatherlat' THEN meta_value END) weatherlat,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'weatherlon' THEN meta_value END) weatherlon
from wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = ***id from Query 1***
```

query 1 returns the following:

```
excerpt  |  id  |  post_title    |  guid
-----------------------------------------
data     |  1   |  example title |  link
data     |  2   |  example title |  link
data     |  3   |  example title |  link
```

query 2 returns the following:

```
post_id  |  allowed  |  amenities  |  trailtype  |  weatherlat  |  weatherlon
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1    |  BOOL     |  a, b, c    |   1         |  53.12       |  -24.123
```

The desired result would be:

```
excerpt  |  id  |  post_title    |  guid  |  allowed  | amenities |  trailtype  |  weatherlat  |  weatherlon
-----------------------------------------
data     |  1   |  example title |  link  |  BOOL     |  a, b, c  |   1         |  53.12      |  -24.123
data     |  2   |  example title |  link  |  BOOL     |  d, e, f  |   2         |  23.67      |  56.42
data     |  3   |  example title |  link  |  BOOL     |  a, b, c  |   1         |  56.152     |  -50.123
```

Answer (score 3):

This would be just syntactically combining your queries:

```
SELECT LEFT(a.post_content, 40) AS excerpt, a.id, a.post_title, a.guid, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'allowed' THEN b.meta_value END) allowed,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'amenities' THEN b.meta_value END) amenities,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'trail-type' THEN b.meta_value END) trailtype,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'weatherlat' THEN b.meta_value END) weatherlat,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'weatherlon' THEN b.meta_value END) weatherlon
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.id = b.post_id
   WHERE a.id IN 
    (SELECT object_id AS id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 74)
```

Comment: Well, I've made a mistake... Query 2 provides a row of data for a single row in the results from query 1 - the join ONLY gives me a single row return...

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what result you actually want to get. Maybe you can provide some demo data?

Comment: SEE APPENDED QUESTION ABOVE

Comment: Try it without `ON a.id = b.post_id`

Comment: Sorry, do not try. Useless.

Comment: The demo data you provided for your second query is wrong you said? It should instead return all rows instead of just one?

Comment: creates a syntax error, tho I can't determine where

Comment: are we reversed in the join?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48170/discussion-between-david-mcclave-and-ghostgambler)

Answer (score 0):

Won't this `where` statement work?

```
where post_id in (SELECT object_id AS id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 74)
```

In the first query, the `id` is set to be one of these `object_id` values.  So, the outer query is not adding anything (or taking anything away).

Comment: I guess I'm not describing the desired results well - sorry.  I'm trying to get the results of query 2 into each row of the results from query 1

Answer (score 0):

After much pain, suffering, and asking 3-4 questions unanswered in full (LOTS of great PART answers - thanks everyone), I've built the statement so that the rows returned are EXACTLY what I wanted.

```
SELECT LEFT(a.post_content, 100) AS excerpt, a.id, a.post_title, a.guid, 
 MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'allowed' THEN b.meta_value END) allowed,
 MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'amenities' THEN b.meta_value END) amenities,
 MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'trail-type' THEN b.meta_value END) trailtype,
 MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'weatherlat' THEN b.meta_value END) weatherlat,
 MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'weatherlon' THEN b.meta_value END) weatherlon
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.id = b.post_id
 WHERE a.id IN (SELECT object_id AS id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 74) group by b.post_id
```

The result is PERFECT!
See: [image: PREFECT RESULTS]